# How do I allign numeric columns of a DataGrid to the right in WPF MVVM approach?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datagridcolumn

I'm binding dynamic collection to `datagrid` from `ViewModel` using MVVM approach like this:

```
var Data = (
    from main in db.MainSaleInvoiceTbls
    join detial in db.DetialSaleInvoiceTbls
    on main.Id equals detial.MainSaleInvoiceId into gDate
    from gdetial in gDate.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where main.IsActive == true
    && main.CompanyId == UniversalInfo.UserCompany.Id
    && main.MainSaleInvoiceDataType == MainSaleInvoiceType.POInvoice
    && main.FinancialYearId == UniversalInfo.SelectedFinancialYear.Id
    orderby main.Id
    select
    new
    {
      Id=main.Id,
      Sr_No=0,
      Date = main.Date.Value,
      Voucher = main.FinancialVoucher,
      Invoice_Account = main.Vendor == null ? string.Empty : main.Vendor.AccountCode,
      Vendor_Name = main.Vendor == null ? string.Empty : main.Vendor.VendorName,
      Vendor_Group = main.Vendor == null ? string.Empty : main.Vendor.VendorGroup.Name,
      Invoice = main.SaleOrderPrefix + main.SaleOrderNumber,
      Purchase_Order = main.SalesId,
      Sales_Tax = "",
      Invoice_Amount= gDate.Sum(x=>x.Quantity * x.UnitPrice)
      });

DataGridCollection = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>(data);
```

XML Code for data binding to grid is:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="miscListDataGrid"  
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" 
                  VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True" 
                  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
                  EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
                  EnableColumnVirtualization="True"  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataGridCollection,IsAsync=True,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"  
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                  Grid.Row="2" 
                  RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" 
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                  CanUserAddRows="False" 
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
                  CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                  IsReadOnly="True" 
                   >
           
        </DataGrid>
```

[image]

my requirement is how do I align the numeric col to right side?
I tried using the `AutoGeneratingColumn` and `RowDetailsVisibilityChanged` events to find out when the DataGrid initialized its columns and fire these events. `AutoGeneratingColumn` fires when columns populating in grid first time. it doesn't allowing to change `CellStyle` or `Alignment` to right side.
If anyone could shed some light on how an event fired to format the columns, it would really help.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should be used when `DataGrid.AutogenerateColumns` is set to `True`.

When creating columns manually in XAML then you simply specify the `DataGridBoundColumn.ElementStyle`.

In both scenarios the `Style` must target the `TextBlock`. This is because the framework will generate a `TextBlock` as cell content host by default (or a `CheckBox` for boolean values).

Cell alignment of a `DataGridTextColumn` is achieved via setting the `TextBlock.TextAlignment` property of the cell content host via the `DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle`.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>    
    <Style x:Key="NumericDataGridCellStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>  

  <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
            AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow
{
  private void DataGrid_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!(e.Column is DataGridTextColumn textColumn))
    {
      return;
    }

    var columnIsNumeric = e.PropertyType == typeof(decimal) 
      || e.PropertyType == typeof(int) 
      || e.PropertyType == typeof(double);
    if (columnIsNumeric)
    {
      var numericCellStyle = FindResource("NumericDataGridCellStyle") as Style;
      textColumn.ElementStyle = numericCellStyle;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how to take it into MVVM Pattern? `OnLoaded()` is not calling in initially when we grid loading in wpf page. it hits second time while navigating to this grid page... is there any alternate event to grid.?

Comment: what's the alternative way to call this method `TryFindResource("NumericDataGridCellStyle") as Style;` in mvvm viewmodel?

Comment: I've updated the code. I now handle the `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn` event and adjusted the handler accordingly. The solution is 100% MVVM. Lookingup UI resources in the view model violates MVVM. You don't handle controls in the view model.

Comment: `FindResource("NumericDataGridCellStyle") as Style;` this gives exception in view model

Comment: I don't understand. Have you tried my code? It definitely works. _How_ can you call `FindResource()` from your view model??? It's a member of `FrameworkElement`. Don't do this in your view model. The view model must be unaware of the view and view related details. Also when getting an exception please show the message.

Comment: Generally `FindResource` throws an exception if the resource couldn't be found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213608/discussion-between-osama-rizwan-and-bioniccode).

Comment: Yes, my example acesses the ResourceDictionary from code-behind. It doesn't vilate MVVM. But handling controls like you did is violating MVVM. MVVM is not about code-behind. It is an architectural design pattern.  Per definition design patterns are language and compiler unspecific. The MVVM design pattern doesn't know about XAML, C# or code behind. Code-behind is realized using the `partial` keyword which is a compiler directive. MVVM's goal is to decouple business logic from the view. e.g. to allow testing your business logic without UI.

Comment: You can apply this pattern on every platform that supports a mechanism to decouple the business logic from the view. The most famous mechanism is data binding, which was invented by Microsoft. Many other platforms and frameworks like Angular allow MVVM. This code-behind paradigm has become popular because most professional developers starting with WPF came from Winforms. The biggest difference between Winforms and WPF is that you have XAML in WPF which allows to split up  UI development and UI logic development. In Winforms everything was done in C#: creating controls, layout and logic.

Comment: Winforms developers that are used to it have difficulties to adopt to the WPF style where XAML is the recommended way to implement UI and UI logic e.g. by using triggers. There are situations where you must handle UI events and the logic is too complex to use `EventTrigger`. You have to use C# in this case. Either in code-behind or in form of an attached behavior. Everything XAML can do C# can too. But XAML is more convenient and requires less code efforts in general. Creating a `DataTemplate` or creating the layout of a `Grid` is so much easier in XAML.

Comment: MVVM is _Do not handle any UI related code (logic, layout or appearance) in your view model! In other words, never access the view from the view model!_Also don't ever access the view model from the model!_ Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed clarity and thorough understanding...